# Java return Component

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, components, awt

I have a problem with my program.
I'm working on the gui, and I can't get it to change the view with this line in the class MenuController:

```
currentComponent = timeRegController.getView().userRegisterTime(user);
```

But I have similar lines, that works just fine. currentComponent an Component that is the current view that the program is showing.

timeRegController.getView() returns a TimeRegistrationPanel called view.

In the class TimeRegistrationPanel I have the following method:

```
public Component userRegisterTime(User user) {
        JPanel window = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        return window;
    }
```

My program says that the problem lies in the line:

```
currentComponent = timeRegController.getView().userRegisterTime(user);
```

because userRegisterTime() is undefined for the type Component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure getView() returns TimeRegistrationPanel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the return value to your `TimeRegistrationPanel` class.

Comment: I tried
currentComponent = ((Object) timeRegController.getView()).userRegisterTime(user);
and currentComponent = (Object) timeRegController.getView().userRegisterTime(user);
But neither works...

Comment: ? Why are you casting to Object? Do you know how casting works? Maybe have a look at the Java tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html